# Select ambiguous view that is not displayed

Tags: android, android-espresso

In my espresso test, I want to select a view by id. The view is below the fold, so I need to `scrollTo()` it. This view shares its id with another view which is hidden.

This gives ambiguous view error:

```
onView(withId(textViewId)).perform(scrollTo(), myAction);
```

So does:

```
onView(allOf(ViewMatchers.isEnabled(), withId(textViewId)))
    .perform(scrollTo(), myAction);
```

This gives no matching view exception:

```
onView(allOf(ViewMatchers.isDisplayed(), withId(textViewId)))
    .perform(scrollTo(), myAction);
```

How can I uniquely select the view I want?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I solved this by identifying a unique ancestor view.

```
onView(allOf(isDescendantOfA(withId(R.id.someParent)), withId(textViewId)))
    .perform(scrollTo(), myAction);
```